# Is List<T>().Count thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, thread-safety

Does anyone know if I need a lock to get the count of items in a List?

Line of code:

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["Name"] as List<Object>`

I'm already doing a lock when adding or removing an object from the list.

Comment: [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

Comment: Yes you need a lock. If you write to a list and read its count you need locks around both. If you only read without any writes, you don't need a lock.

Comment: [Jon Skeet has already ruled upon this matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352360/safe-to-get-count-value-from-generic-collection-without-locking-the-collection)

Comment: Consider using a thread-safe collection from [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx). But even then you need to understand their precise semantics. Thread safety is tricky.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on what you mean by "thread-safe".

For example, is it important that you read the `Count` at a specific point in time? e.g. immediately after an insert/delete, if so, then no it isn't safe to check this without a lock.

Given you are only attempting to pull an integer value the worst case scenario is the value changes after you pull it (which may or may not be important to you). I guess it comes down to how important "staleness" of data is to your application, and that's something only you as the developer can decide.

Comment: `List<T>` is free to even throw an exception in such a case since you must not read and write to a collection at the same time. The current implementation doesn't do so, but there are no guarantees to get even a stale value.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx, `List<T>` is not thread safe:

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, **but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read**. To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation. **To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization**. For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. For an inherently thread–safe alternative, see the ImmutableList class.

Because `.Count` is an instance member, according to the above, it is not thread safe.

Comment: doesnt address the question at all

Comment: They know this though, they have locks on add and remove.

Comment: You can also close vote the question as it has at least two dupes that qualify and you have gained that reputation needed...

Comment: It does address the question as it refers to the documentation.